# to last later for sb

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I do not find "*has lasted later for*" appropriate here. Could sb plese explain it?

Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 711

> iii *Jill still goes to school, whereas Liz is already at university.*
>
> Example [iii] shows still and already in successive clauses contrasting the stage in life that Jill and Liz have reached. **The school stage has lasted later for Jill**, and the university stage has begun earlier for Liz.

Comment: 'lasted later' seems a slightly odd usage to me. I would have said 'lasted longer' or 'lasted until later'.

Comment: @KateBunting hence my post

Comment: Probly just a typo for _has lasted longer_. But It does work.

Comment: @JohnLawler What do mean by "it does work"?

Comment: I mean it's an odd turn of phrase, not idiomatic, but quite understandable.